# If you indicate that the name of the school is not certain yet, would you say "tentative name" or "temporary name" next to the school name?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

I mean if you write the temporary name and put the "tentative" part in the brackets

Comment: You can use Expected School Name..... But I am not sure about your version.

Comment: Are you not decided yet on which school to attend?

Comment: What do you mean by "the school"? Is this a new school?

Answer (score 1):

If the school has an official name it is currently using while trying to decide a new, permanent name, then you would say the currently-used name is "temporary."

If the school doesn't have an official name yet but does have an idea for a name that the school board likes and might decide to use permanently (for example, they might vote on a permanent name next month at the board meeting), then the appropriate label is "tentative."

There is also a "working name," which would be a name that is official but with the idea that the eventual, permanent name will most likely be different. It's very similar to "temporary name."